# Disabling discrete NVIDIA card on ASUS r501vb on 13.10 Saucy, vgaswitharoo or bumblebee?

Tags: nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, vgaswitcheroo

I have a Asus r501vb-s3116d with Intel® HD Graphics 4000 and Nvidia GT 740M (GK107 - 128bit)

I am trying to disable the Nvidia card In Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy and no, I do not have a option to turn off optimus technology in BIOS.

So far browsing forums and reading tutorials I've managed to get here with `vgaswitcharoo`:

```
echo ON > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
echo IGD > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

Output:

```
**0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
1:DIS: :Off:0000:01:00.0**
```

This in turn reduces the core temperatures from 57-60 to 49-51

[The guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics) I am following says:

> `vga_switcheroo` is likely not going to work on these kind of machines. Most Optimus laptops do not have a hardware multiplexer

1. Does this mean the I am one of the lucky ones and this actually worked and there is no need for further hassle?
2. Does this mean that it's not necessarily turned off and I still need to turn to bumblebee?
3. If everything is ok and I do not need to do anything else why is Skype crashing when I launch it with discrete card turned off Error: http://s22.postimg.org/5gkjze2s0/20131212_144414.jpg

4.Why is the script in the tutorial to shut down the nvidia card at boot give this error:

```
     /scripts/local-top/hybrid_boot_options: line 62: can't create /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcharoo/siwtcharoo: nonexistent directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an expert but I also have an Asus laptop (different model though) and I did this to stop the Nvidia card:

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
```

Also have a look at [8 Things To Do After Installing Ubuntu 13.10](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/8-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu.html) (article on Web Upd8). If you ever want to launch an app with the Nvidia card you need to call it with the `optirun` command. The article explains how to create a a link to invoke `optirun`.

Comment: Works for 13.10 (Saucy Salamander) for older versions you need to add the repo manually, but that works good on most platforms!